# PHP Close tags html tags in for each loop

Tags: php, html, css

I have an array named as $links.Now i want to create five links and one HTML container. I want to close tag but I cannot figure out how can I do it

```
$i = 0;
foreach($links as $link)
{
      if($i==0||!is_float($i / 5))
      {
            echo "<div class='container'>"
      }
      echo "<a href='".$link."'>"
      
}
```

Comment: Do you mean you want 5 anchor tags inside one div tag?

Comment: [`array_chunk`](http://php.net/array_chunk) and two loops, if there isn't any more to it.

Comment: @RiggsFolly yes

Comment: Are there always 5 links in `$links`? Or can there be more than 5? Or can there be less than 5?

Comment: @RiggsFolly it can be less than or more than 5

Comment: You may also need to explain what `$link_c` is, or is that your attempt at a counter to 5

Comment: @RiggsFolly it was mistake

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `foreach( $links as $i => $link )` you get a free counter `$i`.

Then just use modulo `%` to close and reopen the div block every 5 links.

```
echo "<div class='container'>";

$lnks = array_values($links);  // make sure you have a numeric index

foreach( $lnks as $i => $link ){
    if (  $i > 0 && $i % 5 == 0 ) {
        // new div block after 5 links
        echo "</div><div class='container'>";
    }
    echo "<a href='$link'>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: Note that this will result in errors and/or wrong behaviour if the array has keys missing or non-numeric keys.

Comment: There's also an `$i > 0` missing in the check, so that it's `if ( $i > 0 && $i % 5 == 0 )`. Otherwise the first element, with index 0, will always close the container right away, leading to an empty container.

Comment: Although I have no idea how to create an array with missing keys, so I cannot test that senario @Fitzi

Comment: e.g. by unsetting an element: `unset($links[5]);`

Comment: Bit if a stretch that one, but the `array_values()` looks after that as well now

Answer (score 2):

As suggested by mario in the comments, you can utilize [array_chunk](https://www.php.net/manual/de/function.array-chunk.php) for that:

```php
$links = range(0,11); // this creates an array with 12 elements, for testing
    
foreach( array_chunk($links, 5) as $chunk ){
    echo '<div class="container">';
    foreach( $chunk as $link ){
        echo '<a href="#' . $link . '">' . $link . '</a>';
    }   
    echo '</div>';
}
```

this would result in

```html
<div class="container">
    <a href="#0">0</a>
    <a href="#1">1</a>
    <a href="#2">2</a>
    <a href="#3">3</a>
    <a href="#4">4</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#5">5</a>
    <a href="#6">6</a>
    <a href="#7">7</a>
    <a href="#8">8</a>
    <a href="#9">9</a>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <a href="#10">10</a>
    <a href="#11">11</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as I've understood, here's the solution

```
$i = 0;
echo "<div class='container'>";
foreach($links as $link)
{
  if($i <=5){
    echo "<a href='".$link."'>";
  }
  $i++;
}
echo "</div>";
```

Answer (score 0):

The div can be output outside of the for loop, and the links inside the for loop.

```
echo "<div class='container'>";
foreach($links as $link)
{
    echo "<a href='".$link."'>";
}
echo "</div>";
```

Comment: i want 5 links in each container

Comment: Are you trying to output multiple divs each with 5 links in them? I saw in the comments you said it could be more or less than 5?

Comment: for example i have 27 links I want 6 divs 5 links in 5 divs and 2 links in 1 div